# Why am I getting error code -551?

Tags: db2, authorization, db2-luw

I just installed the IBM DB2 Express version , using the `db2admin` local account. I am able to connect to the server using DBVisualizer using the latest `db24cc.jar` and URL as `jdbc/localhost:5000/sample`.

When I am in the DBVisualizer I do see Tables Like `ORG` and `DEPT` in the left panel but any `select` running on it gives me error

The error I get is

> SQL ERROR[42501]: The Statement failed because the authorization ID does not required authorization or priviledge to perform the operation. autorization ID:"DB2ADMIN" operation="SELECT" Object="ORG" SQLCODE=-551 SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=4.16.53

I have also added the db2admin to the group DB2ADMNS and DB2USER group

Comment: Is this on Windows? Have you checked [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0023391.html)?

Comment: Yes this is on windows and I have added the db2admin to DBUSERS and DB2ADMNS group

Comment: What user has created the database you're working with and/or the tables in it?

Comment: I didnt created any additional user , at the installation time db2admin was created and was added to my windows machine as administrator, later on I did added the two groups mentioned to it

Comment: `db2admin` or whatever admin user you specify does not get access to databases created by other users. If you ran the installation by a user different from `db2admin`, that user would have created the sample database. If so, connect to the database as the installation user and grant `DBADM` or `DATAACCES` privilege to `db2admin`, if that's what you want.

Comment: You are right I did install the db2 using the domain\username but how do I connect using that . I am using dbbeaver it lets me connect to the IBM DB2 using db2admin but not when i suppole domain\username as username